# Explicit expression for the inverse of an $N\times N$ block matrix $A$ where each $M\times M$ block in $A$ is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I want to invert a non-singular $N\times N$ block matrix $A$ where each $M\times M$ block in $A$ is a diagonal matrix. That is, I have an $N\times N$ block matrix
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
A^{11} & A^{12} & \cdots & \cdots & A^{1N} \\ 
A^{21} & A^{22} &  &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  &  & \ddots &  \\ 
A^{N1} &  &  &  & A^{NN}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where for $i,j \in \{1,\dots,N\}$, each $M\times M$ block $A_{ij}$ is of the form
$$
A_{ij} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & a_{22} &  &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  &  & \ddots &  \\ 
0 &  &  &  & a_{MM}.
\end{pmatrix}
$$

A very simple explicit example where $N=3$ and $M=3$ (with the non-zero diagonals in red for clarity) would be
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{2} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{2} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{3} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{3} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{4} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{5} \\
\color{red}{4} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{5} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{5} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{6} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{7} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{6} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{7} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{8} \\
\color{red}{7} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{8} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{9} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \color{red}{8} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{9} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{9} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Is there a special formula for the inverse a matrix like this, i.e. **is it possible to obtain a special explicit expression for the inverse of an $N\times N$ block matrix $A$ where each $M\times M$ block in $A$ is a diagonal matrix?**

Comment: Permute the rows and columns of $A$ simultaneously to turn $A$ into a block-diagonal matrix. Take the inverse. Then permute back.

Comment: @user1551 "Permute the rows and columns of $A$ simultaneously to turn $A$ into a block-diagonal matrix." How would you do that?

Comment: @amsmath $N=2, M\in \mathbb{N}$ is straightforward using the Schur complement approach to the inverse of a $2\times 2$ block matrix. How it generalize beyond these cases is what I am unsure of.

Comment: It should be computationally easy to solve, using permutations and such, but it seems there will not usually be nice and simple representation. For $M=2$, [link](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/blockmatrixinverse.pdf) shows that it won't have a nice form even with all the $A^{ij}$ being diagonal.

Comment: @sonicboom Why is $M=1$ trivial?

Comment: @amsmath If $M=1$ we have an arbitrary $N\times N$ matrix so there is no special structure to exploit.

Comment: @Shiranai Yes your link essentially derives the Schur complement based inverse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion)

Comment: @sonicboom Oh, I thought the spaces in the block representation of $A$ were supposed to be zeros. But however, then $M=1$ is not at all trivial.

Comment: @amsmath Yes $M=1$ reduces to an arbitrary $N\times N$ matrix so we can't hope for a special expression for the inverse, we need to use some standard matrix inversion process in that case such as Gaussian elimination or LU decomposition. But for $M>1$ we have a very special structure so in that case maybe some special inverse formula is possible.

Comment: @user1551 I'm not sure what you mean, how do we turn $A$ into a block-diagonal matrix?

Comment: "is it possible to obtain an explicit expression for the inverse of an $N\times N$ block matrix $A$ where each $M\times M$ block in $A$ is a diagonal matrix?" Yes. $A^{-1} = (\det A)^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(A)$. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: There is surely not a formula other than the usual ones. But you can make use of the block structure by using a block version of the Gaussian algorithm.

Comment: @amsmath I am looking for a nice expression for the inverse based on the fact that $A$ has a special structure. Similar to how if we had a regular $N\times N$ diagonal matrix we can just invert the elements on the diagonal to get the inverse, which will be much more efficient than computing the general inverse formula $A^{-1} = (det A)^{-1}adj(A)$. That general formula is very poor computationally as it involves computing the determinant.

Comment: @amsmath  user1551 seems to think there is a formula, but I am not sure what he means by permuting rows and columns to obtain a block diagonal version of $A$.

Comment: In fact, your structure is not *that* special. You could try to get a block version of $A^{-1} = (\det A)^{-1}adj(A)$.

Comment: @sonicboom The idea of user1551 works. Here is an example:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&0\\0&3&0&4\\5&0&6&0\\0&7&0&8\end{bmatrix}.$$Now permute rows 2 and 3, then columns 2 and 3. Tricky!

Comment: @ams The inverse of the matrix $A$ in my question will have the same form as the matrix $A$, i.e. it will be an $N\times N$ block matrix, where the $M\times M$ blocks are diagonal. That is certainly a special structure for the inverse of a matrix. Hence why there may be a special explicit representation for the inverse.

Comment: @sonicboom Right. The inverse will have the same form. That's what also follows from user 1551's approach. It reduces your problem to the inversion of $N$ matrices of the format $M\times M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since user1551 doesn't seem to show up anymore, let me make precise their idea here. Each row of your matrix follows a specific pattern. The first one starts with some entry and then $M-1$ zeros, followed by some entry and then $M-1$ zeros and so on. Let's call this Pattern(1). The next row follows Pattern(2) which is just a shifted version of Pattern(1). And so on until Pattern(M) in the $M$-th row. Then we start again with Pattern(1) in the $(M+1)$-th row. Let's now permute the rows such that we sort by patterns. So, first $N$ times Patten(1), then $N$ times Pattern(2) and so on. Then we obtain a $M\times N$ block matrix with blocks of size $N\times M$:
$$
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
B^{11} & B^{12} & \cdots & \cdots & B^{1N} \\ 
B^{21} & B^{22} &  &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  & \ddots &  &  \\ 
\vdots &  &  & \ddots &  \\ 
B^{M1} &  &  &  & B^{MN}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here, for any block-row $k$, $B^{k1},\ldots,B^{kN}$ all have the same form, namely each column being zero except the $k$-th. Now, let us consider the columns of $B$. They are all of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\ \vdots\\ v_M\end{bmatrix}
$$
with each $v_j$ being an $N\times 1$-vector and *only one of them is not the zero vector*. Sorting the columns by pattern will then result in an $M\times M$ block-diagonal matrix with $N\times N$-matrices as entries.

Comment: Yes this seems correct. So we perform this process, invert the resulting block-diagonal matrix and 'unperform' the process.  Recursive Schur complements could also be used (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00001.pdf).

Comment: About the 'unperform' procedure: You find permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ$ has the above block-diagonal form. So $A^{-1} = Q(PAQ)^{-1}P$.